# Liferay-Spring-Portlet ModelAttribute's values are not set

Tags: java, spring, liferay, portlet

I have to write a portlet with Spring which simply gets some user inputs.
First of all I put a custom object to a Model in the render method in the controller. In the jsp file I can access this object, and with a form I want to set the object's parameters. (I use `<form:form ...>` for setting values).

After the submit button I want to get the object with the requested method with `@ModelAttribute` parameter. But the object's params are unchanged, they are nulls. If I set one of them before adding the object to the model, I will get this value after the submit button, but I can't change it.
The requested method is annotated with `@ActionMapping(params = "action=actionName")`

This is the controller:

```
@Controller(value = "SpringMVCController")
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class SpringMVCController {


    @RenderMapping
    public String handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("reservation", new Reservation());
        return "defaultPage";
    }


    @ActionMapping(params = "action=addReservation") 
     public void addReservation(@ModelAttribute("reservation") Reservation reservation, BindingResult result,
             ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {

        System.out.println(reservation.getUrl());
     }

}
```

This is the jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>



<portlet:defineObjects/>

<portlet:actionURL var="addReservationURL">
 <portlet:param name="action" value="addReservation"></portlet:param>
</portlet:actionURL>


<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="reservation" action="${addReservationURL}">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>From where(URL): </td>
            <td><form:input path="url"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="OK" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Comment: We may need to see the code, but are you talking about submitted data being captured automatically from your submit?  That would use `@RequestParam`.

Comment: Tomorrow I'm going to post the code.

Comment: In the meantime, [this post](http://charles.forsythe.name/home/-/blogs/spring-mvc-modelattribute-tag-advanced-examples) might help.  I'm not sure it's applicable, but I thought I'd toss it out there.

Comment: I have posted the code.

Comment: try to change modelAttribute="reservation" to commandName="reservation"

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried small spring portlet example. My form also not submitted but then I have found that
 [Spring MV Porlet ActionMapping is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953079/spring-mv-porlet-actionmapping-is-not-working)

Then I changed my spring version to 3.2.3.RELEASE but this take no effect, form still not submitted.
After that I changed spring form tags to pure html form tags and everything became fine.

```
<form method="post" action="${url}">
```